# Objective-C - Hello World app modification

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm just learning to do the "Hello, World" app. But I have a question. I'd like to change the code so the result reads "World, Hello" but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the original code:

```
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

self.userName = self.textField.text;

NSString *nameString = self.userName;
if ([nameString length] == 0) {
    nameString = @"World";
}
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];
    self.label.text = greeting;
}
```

and I thought it would work if I could change it to:

```
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

self.userName = self.textField.text;

NSString *nameString = self.userName;
if ([nameString length] == 0) {
    nameString = @"World";
}
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:nameString , @"Hello, %@!"];
    self.label.text = greeting;
}
```

However that still didn't work. What would I do to make that work?

Comment: I must ask, is that IBAction hooked up?

Answer (score 5):

Change this line

```
NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:nameString , @"Hello, %@!"];
```

To

```
NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@, Hello!", nameString];
```

`initWithFormat`, uses place holder when you write `@"%@, Hello!"` the `"%@"` indicates that the following string `nameString` will be replaced by it 
So when we `@"%@, Hello!"` we really mean `@"nameString, Hello!"` (nameString in your example is World)